# How to configure console of azure devops pipeline powershell task to properly format Write-* Cmdlets' output?

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm using the following [PowerShell task](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell):

> ```
> 2022-12-09T04:30:32.5910772Z Task         : PowerShell
> 2022-12-09T04:30:32.5911006Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
> 2022-12-09T04:30:32.5911196Z Version      : 2.212.0
> 2022-12-09T04:30:32.5911349Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> 2022-12-09T04:30:32.5911615Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
> ```

Here is an example warning output where you can see the message is surrounded by `[33;1m` and `[0m`. I assume these are [ANSI escap codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters).

```
2022-12-09T04:30:30.8803823Z [33;1mWARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( /root/.Azure ). Please ensure that this directory has appropriate protections.[0m
```

Here is an example Error message output:

```
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5319115Z [91mInvoke-RestMethod: [0m/azp/agent/_work/r2/a/_ADsync-Utility/adsync/ADsyncUtility/adbusersync.ps1:254
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5320715Z [96mLine |
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5322096Z [96m 254 | [0m … sResponse = [96mInvoke-RestMethod $adbGroupsURL -Method GET -Headers $adb[0m …
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5323707Z [96m     | [91m               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5325002Z [91m[96m     | [91m{"error_code":"403","message":"Invalid access to Org:
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5326245Z [96m     | [91m2660194586577136"}
2022-12-09T04:30:39.5327021Z [0m
```

As a workaround, is there a way that I can configure the format of Powershell Write-Verbose, Write-Warning and Write-Error cmdlets' messages to remove these escape codes and/or possibly use the [Azure DevOps Logging Command Formatting syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#formatting-commands)?

- ##[warning]Warning message
- ##[error]Error message

Comment: Check if `$PSStyle.OutputRendering` is ANSI. If it is, change it to `Host` or `PlainText`: `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText'` (place it at the top of your code)

Comment: Have you checked the $PSStyle.OutputRendering?

Comment: The value was 'Ansi'.  Changing it to 'Host' did not fix it.  Changing it to 'PlainText' fixed the formatting of warnings, but when I write-error I still get the ansi formatting.  When I set the value does it only apply inside my script? Maybe the error is actually written outside of the context of my script because $ErrorActionPreference=Stop.  I'm not sure.  Any ideas?